# How can I integrate Google Suggest with Magento address?

Tags: magento-1.9

I searched after some ideas how to achieve this and I couldn't find any hint. I know that there is a module which uses this but I am not interested to buy it only for this option. 
The link with the module
http://www.magestore.com/magento-one-step-checkout-extension.html

Answer (score 3):

[@fbrnc](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/213/fbrnc) and the guys from AOE made up an extension called `Aoe_AddressAutoComplete` which does exactly that and which is on [GitHub](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_AddressAutoComplete). Though they say it is highly experimental, it may be a good source for you to have a look how they did it. Ideally, if you have any issues with the extension, you can fix the code and send them a pull request.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the google api for [Autocomplete for Addresses and Search Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)

In your onepage checkout address template you would need to slightly modify [Autocomplete for address forms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms) ([live example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform))

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a free solution three years later. I found this module on [Github](https://github.com/Turiknox/magento-address-autocomplete). It works great for Magento 1.8.x and 1.9.x and I've been easily able to modify it for a custom checkout.

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate Google Suggest with Magento address, you don't need to buy the One step checkout extension but a separate Google Address Autocomplete extension. There are some free and paid ones.

Another similar extension that provides the autocomplete function when the customers type their addresses is this [Magento 2 Address Autocomplete](https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-address-autocomplete/). Different from the Google Suggest extensions, it doesn't use Google API and you can import the addresses into your database. In the frontend, when the users enter one of the shipping fields (city, state/province, subdistrict, zip/postal code), it will immediately suggest some related addresses taken from the database, and then once an address is selected, all of the remaining fields will be auto-filled instantly.